# Добавить div к каждому циклу foreach

Tags: php

При запросе к базе, Я получаю массив данных:

```
$pricelist = GetServiceList();

function GetServiceList (){
$QueryText = "SELECT id, name, price FROM healthproc
WHERE parentid IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = Query($QueryText);

   return $result;
```

}

После этого мне надо каждый массив обернуть в блок div. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: "При запросе к базе я получаю [один] массив данных. После этого мне надо **каждый** массив обернуть в блок div".  Каждый из одного?

Comment: @Ипатьев каждый массив = каждую строку результата, видимо

Comment: @teran поразительно. сам бы я ни за что не догадался

Comment: 1 массив это id+name+price

Comment: @Ипатьев рад, что помог!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот этот метод сработал

```
<?php  
foreach (array_chunk($pricelist, true) as $array) {
   foreach($array as $price) {
echo '<div data-item-id="'.$price->ID.'">'.$price->NAME.' '.$price->PRICE.' грн.</div>';
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: это полная бессмыслица. надо было просто перебрать foreach ($pricelist, как вам написали выше. без этих дурацких телодвижений

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = "";
foreach($result AS $item){
   $html .= "<div>".$item['id']."</div>";
   $html .= "<div>".$item['name']."</div>";
   $html .= "<div>".$item['price']."</div>";
}
```

или

```
foreach($result AS $item){
       $html .= "<div>".$item['id']."/".$item['name']."/".$item['price']."</div>";
    }
```

Comment: id/name/price = это 1 массив должен быть
то есть в одном div должны быть id/name/price

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]